# How do you call a method from another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question for you please.
Ths situation is like this:
I have a method specified in this namespace: `namespace IkubInfo.NE.Web.UI`
the method is like this :  `protected void Export2(GridView gv, object data, string title)`

I need to call this method in another page which doesn't have the same namespace.
How can I call this method inside this method : `protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` ?

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's impossible because it's protected. You need to make it public if possible. Can you? If so , we can help you in advance.

Comment: Ok, If I make it public can you show me how to call it please ? Thank you.

Comment: you need change `Export2` to _public_, possibly _static_, and use `using IkubInfo.NE.Web.UI` or full name class

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years - not true, you can always use reflection for this kind of ugly stuff; unless it is 3pty over which you have no control  I agree with Amiros - move the shared stuff to separate manager/service that will handle it.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar Thanks for new information for me. Is it a security hole for protected? Or is there any more protection for method?

Comment: I made it public and also added the following line in the page I want to call the method:   using IkubInfo.NE.Web.UI   How am I supposed to call this method: public void Export2(GridView gv, object data, string title) now ?

Comment: @Marin change it to _static_, and try `YourPageClass.Export2(...)`

Answer (score 2):

I assume we are talking about business logic that doesn't have any UI touches.

The best practice is to move this logic into managers\services that sit in different dll's and call them via the events.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my question, also thanks to all of your advices.

Firstly I used this line:  `using IkubInfo.NE.Web.UI;`

Than, all I had to do is to call the method like this: `this.Export2(value1, value2, value3);`

inside the button click events which calls the method. I hope this solution would help anybody else in this forum. Thank you for all the support!